In Angular 17, In upload file functionality. Can we check if there are some unwanted objects in the uploaded file? (.exe files might be)
I have an upload file functionality in my screen, where the user can upload files that can be pdf file, excel file, etc.
To keep a check on security vulnerability that can be caused to my system. I want to check if there are some malicious objects in the uploaded file, I won't take that file to my server instead giving a validation to the user.
For Eg: I have allowed .xlsx files. But someone added an .exe file(Embedded file) as an object in a excel file. And tried uploading this excel file. I want to stop these kind of file uploads

There's no client-based solution. The best option is to add virus-scanning to middleware on your API that dumps any file that fails the scan.

Yes seems like the only option.
